# Array em PHP que não está a obter valores

Tags: php, array, for

O objetivo do exercicio era criar um array de 20 numeros que variem entre -100 e 100. Tenho que fazer a distinção entre valores negativos e positivos. Se for positivo tenho que adicionar o valor na sua totalidade a uma variavel e se forem negativos tenho que contar +1 para um contador (ou seja, somar positivos e contar o numero de negativos).

Por alguma razão estou a conseguir contar os negativos mas não estou a conseguir fazer o calculo da soma dos positivos nem mostrar o array.

Assumo que seja o array que não esteja a ser guardado corretamente. O meu código é o seguinte:

```
<html>
 <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>PHP Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>

    <?php   
     function random(){
         $vec = array();
         $neg = 0;
         $pos = 0;

            for ($i=1; $i<=20; $i++) {
                $temp = rand(-100, 100);
                $vec = $temp;

                if ($temp <= 0) {
                    $neg++;
                } else {
                    $pos+=$vec;
                }
            }


         echo "Soma dos Positivos </br>" . $sum . "Numero de negativos " . $neg . "</br>";

                 for ($i=1; $i<=20; $i++) {
                     return $vec[$i];
                 }        
        } 

        random();
    ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Não tinha visto que era para exibir a cada iteração, corrigi minha resposta da uma olhada :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não estava atribuindo ao vetor o valor da forma correto:

```
$vec = $temp;
```

Desta forma ele só retornaria o primeiro valor:

```
for ($i=1; $i<=20; $i++) {
    return $vec[$i];
}
```

Resultado:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>PHP Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        $vec = array();
        $neg = 0;
        $pos = 0;

        for ($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++) {
            $temp = rand(-100, 100);
            $vec[$i] = $temp;

            if ($temp <= 0) {
                $neg++;
            } else {
                $pos += $vec[$i];
            }
        }


        echo "Soma dos Positivos " . $pos .
        "</br>Numero de negativos " . $neg . "</br>";

        for ($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++) {
            echo $vec[$i] . "</br>";
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Saída:

```
Soma dos Positivos 756
Numero de negativos 8
19
66
-37
71
-57
89
47
-67
57
83
12
-67
-62
-75
68
-95
69
-77
92
83
```

Answer (score 1):

Apenas para diferenciar das outras respostas, você pode não usar `if` e na verdade nem usar `>` ou `<` se quiser.

Você pode criar uma array e fazer a mesma operação independente de se o valor é ou não negativo ou positivo, depois apenas pegar os dados que precisa, um exemplo:

```
<?php

$msb = PHP_INT_SIZE * 8;
$resultado = [0 => ['qnt' => 0, 'total' => 0], 1 => ['qnt' => 0, 'total' => 0]];

for ($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++){
    $n = random_int(-100, 100);

    $isNegativo = ($n >> $msb) & 1;
    $resultado[$isNegativo]['qnt'] += 1;
    $resultado[$isNegativo]['total'] += $n;

    echo  $n . PHP_EOL;
}

echo 'Total dos positivos: ' . $resultado[0]['total'] . PHP_EOL;
echo 'Quantidade de negativos: ' . $resultado[1]['qnt'] . PHP_EOL;
```

[Teste isto aqui.](https://ideone.com/L7wyJJ)

O `$isNegativo` move o bit mais significante, que será sempre `-1` ou `0`, porque o `>>` ainda mantem o sinal. Então se ele for `-1` podemos fazer o `& 1` afim de que que ele se torne 1 para negativo e 0 para positivo.

Depois, em ambos os casos, inserimos o resultado na array e apenas mostramos o que é preciso.

---

Uma outra opção usando `<` e `if`, seria:

```
<?php

$resultado = [0 => 0, 1 => 0];

for ($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++){
    $n = random_int(-100, 100);

    $resultado[$n < 0] += $n < 0 ? 1 : $n;

    echo  $n . PHP_EOL;
}

echo 'Total dos positivos: ' . $resultado[0] . PHP_EOL;
echo 'Quantidade de negativos: ' . $resultado[1] . PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Você incrementou os valores na variável `$pos` mas tentou exibir os valores de `$sum`, outra coisa que você não está fazendo é exibir os valores do vetor a cada iteração.

[Veja funcionando](https://ideone.com/YoDdLW)

Segue código completo, abaixo:

```
<?php
function random(){
    $neg = 0;
    $pos = 0;
    $vet = array();

    echo "Números sorteados: ";
    for ($i=1; $i<=20; $i++) {
        $temp = rand(-100, 100);
        $vet[$i] = $temp;

        if ($temp <= 0) {
            $neg++;
        } else {
            $pos+=$temp;
        }


        // Obs.: você poderia exibir tudo sem utilizar um array apenas com a variavel $temp, mas como o exercício pediu, deixei a solução abaixo com o array:    
        if($i==20){
            echo $vet[$i] . "</br>";
        }else{
            echo $vet[$i] . ",";
        }

    }

    echo "Soma dos Positivos: " . $pos . "</br> Quantidade de negativos: " . $neg . "</br>";      
} 

random();
?>
```